# How to install a specific commit of Frama-C

Tags: frama-c

An [issue](https://bts.frama-c.com/view.php?id=2283) in the bug-tracking system of Frama-C contains a note:

> "was fixed by commit xyz. Fix will appear in Phosphorus."

How do I update frama-c to that specific commit? I installed frama-c on Ubuntu via opam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am a Frama-C developer.) The individual commits are currently not accessible to non-developers, and I've modified the BTS issue accordingly. We release snapshot versions of Frama-C every 6 months. We expect the release of Phosphorus, which will contain this particular fix, to happen in May.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the clarification.